# Conditional expectation of $X$ given $Z$, where $Z = 1$ if $X > Y$ and $-1$, otherwise

Tags: probability, self-learning, conditional-expectation

Let $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Exp}(2)$ be independent random variables. Define $Z$ by

$$
Z = 
\begin{cases}
1,& X>Y\\
-1,& X\leqslant Y.
\end{cases}
$$
I want to calculate $E[X|Z]$.

Not quite sure which formula to use because $Z$ is discrete and $X$ is continuous?

If I use this formula, would this be a good start?

$$ E[X|Z] = \sum_x x P(X = x|Z = z) = \sum_x x \frac{P(X = x, Z = z)}{P(Z = z)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to put this in comments instead but not enough yet so I apologize.

Here is a naive method that may help you get going and pretty easy to understand.

Recall for joint density
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f(x)f(y|X=x)=f(y)f(x|Y=y)
$$
So
$$
E[X|Z]=\int_X x\cdot f(x|Z=z)dx=\int_X x\cdot \frac{f_X(x)P(Z=z | X=x)}{P(Z=z)}dx
$$
Then you can plug $z=\{1,-1\}$ and work it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I plug in z = 1, and z = -1 do I have to sum over z as well? I ask this because P(Z = 1) is different from P(Z = -1) so which one would I use in the formula?

Comment: That would depend on Z. It should give you different answer for different values of z. For intuition, the expectation of scoring a goal given you're Messi is different than scoring a goal given you're not Messi.